# How to create a loop that populates a variable-sized matrix with COUNTIFS?

Tags: excel, vba, countif

It's rather a complex situation. I have a routine that needs to be done every other day. I have a workbook with 2 different sheets, one called "deals list", contains a table like this:

| Salesman | Campaign |
| --- | --- |
| Name 1 | Campaign A |
| Name 1 | Campaign B |
| Name 2 | Campaign C |
| Name 3 | Campaign A |
| Name N | Campaign N |

The other sheet, called "matrix", is generated by a VBA code the currently results in something like this:

|  | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 | Name N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign A |  |  |  |  |
| Campaign C |  |  |  |  |
| Campaign A |  |  |  |  |
| Campaign N |  |  |  |  |

This variable-sized matrix can change the size of columns and rows based on the report I get. The actual workbook has much more content, I am just simplifying it with these examples. You can notice the empty cells because I don't know how to create the code to fill them. What I actually desire to be inside them is the number of campaigns each salesman is assigned to.

Desired Result:

|  | Name 1 | Name 2 | Name 3 | Name N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Campaign A | 1 | 0 | 1 | N |
| Campaign B | 1 | 0 | 0 | N |
| Campaign C | 0 | 1 | 0 | N |
| Campaign N | N | N | N | N |

Basically what I need is to use the first row and column as parameters for a COUNTIFS to populate the matrix.

Can anyone help me with that? I'd really appreciate any tips coming my way! ;)

This is my first question in the community, I ask sorry in advance if I've done any mistakes. I feel ashamed to ask but I have no clue whatsoever on how to do this.

```
Function FnTwoDimentionDynamic()

   Dim arrTwoD()
   Dim intRows
   Dim intCols
   Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

   intRows = Sheets("matrix").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
   intCols = Sheets("matrix").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1

   ReDim Preserve arrTwoD(1 To intRows, 1 To intCols)

'Here I am using a simple calculation just to see if will populate
'the variable range, but what I need is a COUNTIFS searching for
'the times a Salesman appears in certain Campaing
For i = 1 To intRows
    For j = 1 To intCols
        arrTwoD(i, j) = i * 2 + j ^ 2 
    Next j
Next i
Sheets("matrix").Select: Range("B2").Select
For i = 1 To intRows
    For j = 1 To intCols
        ActiveCell.Value = arrTwoD(i, j)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next j
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, -intCols).Select
Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far? What research have you done? What part is not working for you? Make an attempt, for the SO community to help you troubleshoot. Meanwhile, your description of what you want to achieve is clear so is a great start.

Comment: Hey! Thanks! :D

Comment: @diogohslenzi Don't post code in a comment, edit the original question and add it there - makes it easier to read and copy.;)

Comment: @norie Thanks! Hahaha! Newbies right? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code makes a couple of assumptions, the first being that you are using Excel 365 and the data on the sheet `deals list` starts in A1.

If either of these are incorrect the code can be changed.

Also, I'm not sure how you are creating your 'matrix' so I've used code to do that at the start.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CreateMatrixAndCounts()
Dim wsDeals As Worksheet
Dim wsMatrix As Worksheet
Dim rngSalesmen As Range
Dim rngCampaigns As Range
Dim rngFormulas As Range

Dim arrUniqueSalesmen As Variant
Dim arrUniqueCampaigns As Variant

    Set wsDeals = Sheets("Deals List")
    
    With wsDeals
        Set rngSalesmen = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set rngCampaigns = rngSalesmen.Offset(, 1)
        arrUniqueSalesmen = Application.Sort(Application.Unique(rngSalesmen))
        arrUniqueCampaigns = Application.Sort(Application.Unique(rngCampaigns))
    End With
    
    Set wsMatrix = Sheets.Add
    
    wsMatrix.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arrUniqueSalesmen)).Value = arrUniqueSalesmen
    wsMatrix.Range("B1").Resize(, UBound(arrUniqueCampaigns)).Value = Application.Transpose(arrUniqueCampaigns)
    
    Set rngFormulas = wsMatrix.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrUniqueSalesmen), UBound(arrUniqueCampaigns))
    
    With rngSalesmen
        rngFormulas.Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & .Address(External:=True) & ", $A2, " & .Offset(, 1).Address(External:=True) & ", B$1)"
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Works perfectly and super fast! Thank you so much @norie! Amazing!!! I can't upvote your answer tho, because I have to have 15 pts of reputation... But thank you SO MUCH!

Comment: Hey @norie! Sorry to bother you again... I noticed a little problem using your code today. The COUNTIFS are counting hidden rows as well and for my purpose they should not. Is there a good way to fix that?

Comment: Have you considered not using code? You could probably use a pivot table to get the results you want, and with a pivot table you would be able to filter the data.

Comment: I really did, the thing is that this is done at least 4 times a week and it is quite an important step in my routine of work. I want to eliminate human errors as well... :T